Why doesn't a common_type_t result in a common type?
Consider this code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<template <class ...> class Container, typename ... Args>
Container<common_type_t<remove_cvref_t<Args> ...>> fn( Args &&... args );

int main()
{
    for( int i : fn<vector>( 1, 2.6, 3 ) )
        cout << i << ", " << endl;
    // prints correct type ...
    cout << typeid(common_type_t<int, double>).name() << endl;
}

template<template <class ...> class Container, typename ... Args>
Container<common_type_t<remove_cvref_t<Args> ...>> fn( Args &&... args )
{
    Container<common_type_t<remove_cvref_t<Args> ...>> cont;
    (cont.emplace_back( forward<Args>( args ) ), ...);
    return cont;
}

Unfortunately the container's type is an int and not a float as you might guess from the parameter pack. Why is that ?
The compiler gives a warning for the function call of fn<>
'initializing': conversion from '_Ty' to 'int', possible loss of data


int -> auto. Typo?

Your problem is here:
for( int i : fn<vector>( 1, 2.6, 3 ) )
        cout << i << ", " << endl;

fn<...> returns the correct type, but you convert it to int. Replace int i --> auto i in the loop.
